landscape-sysinfo reported 1 month old info at login
This morning I was investigating high cpu usage on a server on ec2, and at ssh login I was greeted with this:
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.5.0-1021-aws x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/pro

  System information as of Wed Jun 26 11:43:31 CEST 2024

  System load:                      0.24658203125
  Usage of /:                       99.4% of 28.89GB
  Memory usage:                     61%
  Swap usage:                       0%
  Processes:                        150
  Users logged in:                  0
  IPv4 address for br-3a1ae2202054: <redacted>
  IPv4 address for docker0:         <redacted>
  IPv4 address for ens5:            <redacted>

  => / is using 99.4% of 28.89GB

I immediately checked df and it reported a lot of free disk space.
Then I opened a second connection and I got:
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.5.0-1021-aws x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/pro

  System information as of Fri Jul 26 09:08:36 CEST 2024

  System load:                      0.3408203125
  Usage of /:                       41.6% of 28.89GB
  Memory usage:                     37%
  Swap usage:                       0%
  Processes:                        160
  Users logged in:                  1
  IPv4 address for br-f5629a6705b7: <redacted>
  IPv4 address for docker0:         <redacted>
  IPv4 address for ens5:            <redacted>

And then I noticed that the date in the first report was from a month ago. How is that possible? I thought that those info where obtained on the fly from the landscape-sysinfo command.
